Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function such that $f(n)=1$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then which is of the following is true?
Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function such that $f(n)=1$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then
A. $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.
B. Range of $f$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.
C. Range of $f$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.
D. None of the above.
My attempte: If we choose $f$ as a constant function $1$ we can discard C immediately.
I think both A and B should be correct.
For A as $f$ is continuous on each $[n,n+1]$ it is uniformly continuos on that interval. from that can I conclude $f$ is uniformly continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$?
Similarly for B $f$ has closed compact range on each interval [n,n+1]. from that can I conclude $f$ has closed range on whole $\mathbb{R}$?
Can someone help me for the these options please?

"For A as $f$ is continuous on each $[n,n+1]$..." et cetera: those considerations would be true of any continuous function, regardless of being $1$ on $\Bbb Z$. Same for "Similarly for B..." et cetera.

Try some examples, such as $1+x\sin x$.

You should be able to come up with counterexamples  to both by creating functions that are successively "worse"on each interval, where what "worse" means in each case is part of the exercise left for you to figure out.

Imagine that, on each interval $[n,n+1]$, $f$ increases to $3-1/n$, then goes back down to 1. (Ignore the negatives, or say $f(x)=1$ for $x<0$.) What is the range?

Similar to Sambo's example, suppose that, on each interval $[n,n+1]$, $f$ increases to $n$, then goes back down to 1. This function is still continuous and differentiable, but is it uniformly continuous?

Let $$f(x)=1+\sin^2(\pi x^2)\left [1-{1\over 1+x^2}\right ]$$ The minimal value is equal $1.$ The function is bounded above by $2.$ Moreover $f(x_n)\to 2$ for $x_n= 2^{-1/2}(2n+1)^{1/2}.$ Hence the range of $f$  is equal $[1,2).$ The function $g(x):=\sin^2(\pi x^2)$ is not uniformly continuous. Indeed for   $y_n=n^{1/2}$  we have $g(x_n)-g(y_n)=1$ and $x_n-y_n\to 0.$ The function  $h(x):=1-{\sin^2(\pi x^2)\over 1+x^2}$ is uniformly continuous. Hence $f=h+g$ is not uniformly continuous. Thus $f$ does not satisfy A,B,C.

To reject $B$, consider the map
$$f(x) = 1-\frac{x^2\sin^2(\pi x)}{1+x^2}.$$
Clearly $f(x)\geq 0$, for all $x$. Also $f(n)=1$, for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that for $x=n\frac{\pi}{2}$, $n$ being odd,
$$f(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2},$$
which goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$. But for no $x$, $f(x)=0$. Because,
$$f(x)=0 \implies 1+x^2 = x^2\sin^2(\pi x),$$
which cannot happen as
$$1\neq x^2(\sin^2(\pi x)-1),$$
for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
Thus $0$ is a limit point of range which is not in range. Hence the range cannot be closed.
Now, to reject $A$, consider the map
$$f(x) = 1-x^2\sin^2(\pi x)$$
Now, if $x= \frac{n\pi}{2}$, where $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then for any $y$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)| = |x^2 -y^2\sin^2\pi y| = |x+y\sin \pi y||x-y\sin \pi y| \geq |x+y\sin \pi y||x-y|.$$
Now, whatever $\delta$ (sufficiently small) is fixed, we can find sufficiently large $n$ ($n\equiv 1\pmod 4$), such that there is a point $y$ around $x=n\frac{\pi}{2}$ with $|x-y|=\frac{\delta}{2}$, $\sin \pi y$ is positive and $|x+y\sin \pi y| = x+y\sin \pi y > \frac{2}{\delta}$. Thus
$$|f(x)-f(y)| > 1.$$
This is true for any $\delta$ chosen. Thus $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

How did you come up with these examples?

I thought of constructing a function which is unbounded, never takes a value, say $a$, but goes as much closer as pleased to $a$. I knew about $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ and guessed the function $f(x)$ defined here after some trial and errors in mind. For the second one,  I knew $x^2$ on $\mathbb{R}$ was not uniformly continuous and hit upon this example which seemed to work. I guess the examples work. Don't they?

I should look at them more carefully but I trust you :) I was just interested in your process of creating counterexamples. By the way, probably you meant that the first function goes to $0$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$, not $n$

No I don't know what happens to $f$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$. However, there is a sequence of reals ${n\frac{\pi}{2}}$ for which $f$ approaches $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Thus, $0$ turns out to be a limit point of the range.

Ooooh now I see what you mean, sorry, I thought you had made a typo because there was no $n$ in the definition of $f(x)$

Some examples using the sine function.
$f(x) = 1 + x \sin(2\pi x)$ is not uniformly continuous on the real line - so A fails.
$f(x) = 1, x<1$ and $f(x) = 1 + \tfrac{x-1}{x} \sin(2\pi x), x\geq 1$ has range $(0,2)$ - so B fails.
$f(x) = 1 + \sin(2\pi x)$ has range $[0,2]$ - so C fails.
